If a function is increasing in all rational numbers and is continuous in all real numbers, is it increasing $(x>y⟹F(x)≥F(y))$ in real numbers as well?
I was trying to prove the monotonicity of $\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}$ and ended up proving it for rational numbers, how can I extend this proof for real numbers as well

Use the density of the irrationals in the reals, perhaps.

Hint:  Suppose not.  Then there is some pair $x>y$ with $F(x)<F(y)$.  Now use continuity to show that we must be able to find rationals $x',y'$ "near enough" to $x,y$.

Should say:  I am assuming that, by "increasing" you mean $x>y\implies F(x)≥F(y)$, but you should edit your post to clarify this point.

here is a duplicate that assumes "strictly increasing", but it received no proper answers.

Let $x \leq y$ be real numbers. Then there exists an increasing sequence of rational numbers $q_n \nearrow x$ and a decreasing sequence of rational numbers $p_n \searrow y$. Thus, $q_n \leq x \leq y \leq p_n$, and as $f$ is increasing in rational numbers, $f(q_n) \leq f(p_n)$. Now, letting $n \to \infty$ shows $f(x) \leq f(y)$.
